# How to check if a string doesn't have any alpha numeric characters?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, gdb, strcmp

I get a segmentation fault error whenever I compare

```
strcmp(commands[i].cmd[0],"quit") == 0)
```

and

> commands[i].cmd[0] is of type char *.

and this happens when

> cmd[0] = 0x0

according to my gdb debugger.

Now this happens when also no alpha numeric characters are present. I.e a string with just spaces for example. How would I avoid that. I want to check that my string has at least a symbol.

That is the error that causes my segmentation fault

**Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strcmp.S:213
213     movlpd  (%rdi), %xmm1**

Comment: Post your complete code. Without that it's nearly impossible to point out the error.

Comment: *"`commands[i].cmd[0]` is of type `char *` and this happens when `cmd[0] = 0x0`"*. You are showing that you are passing a `NULL` pointer to `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int isalnumstr(const char *str)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; str[i]; ++i)
        if (isalnum((unsigned char) str[i]))
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Caller code:

```
if (isalnumstr(s))
    /* Contains alpha numeric */
else
    /* Doesn't contain alpha numeric */
```

Comment: 1) `if (isalnum(str[i])` missing `)`.  2) `isalnum(x)` is defined for all `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  If `x` is negative and not `EOF` can lead to UB.  Better: `if ((unsigned char) isalnum(str[i]))`

Comment: why would i need to cast the return value of `isalnum`, if it returns an `int`? @chux

Comment: My mistake.  Meant to suggest `if (isalnum((unsigned char)  str[i]))`

Comment: fixed @chux [15 chars]